# Binary Zero, NULL Byte and ASCII

Tags: null, byte, ascii

I am very confused. Is there any relationship between the following:

1. Binary Zero.
2. Null Byte.
3. ASCII Character 0 (Decimal value is 48).

Your explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you read those terms (especially the first one)? What is the context? It might help with giving a better answer.

Comment: I was reading the PHP manual page about escape sequences. The page mentioned "binary zero". Here is a link to the page http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php.

Comment: It seems that site uses "binary zero" to refer to a null byte (i.e. in this case the terms are synonyms).

Answer (score 3):

Technically, I suppose the first refers to a single bit. Eight bits make a byte, and eight binary zeros would thus comprise a "null byte", the byte with numeric value `0` which is used to terminate C strings. The ASCII value used to represent the text character `0` is, as you say, 48, and there is nothing special about that value -- it's just the more or less random number that was assigned to this duty.